# FASM concurrent increment and CPU load

Tags: assembly, concurrency, fasm

I'm experimenting with FASM in order to improve my understanding of concurrency. I've created a program that has two threads each making some number of `lock xadd`. I run it on my Win7 64bit on i7 and I'm getting quite interesting results. While the program itself works correctly it loads 4 cores instead of two as I expected.

Task Manager's "Performance" shows clear load of 4 cores
[image]

Resource Monitor's, CPU tab shows that my process has two threads

Could someone give a hint on why does that happen? Is there a way to tell which core is currently running a piece of code from my FASM program (just to make sure that the cores are indeed different)?

```
format PE console
include 'win32ax.inc'
include 'macro32.inc'
entry main

section '.code' code readable executable
main:
        invoke CreateThread, 0, 0, atomic_inc, 0, 0, 0
        mov [threadHandle], eax
        call atomic_inc
        invoke WaitForSingleObject, dword[threadHandle], 0xFFFFFFFF

        ;cinvoke printf, "B - %u", dword [myInt]

        invoke system, halt
        invoke exit, 0

        proc atomic_inc, lpParam
          mov ebx, 1000000000
          startloop:
            cmp ebx, 0
            jz endofloop
            push ebx

            ; Loop body
            mov eax, 1
            lock
            xadd dword [myInt], eax

            pop ebx
            dec ebx
            jmp startloop
          endofloop:
          ret
        endp


section '.data' data readable writable
        halt db "pause>null",0
        myInt dd 0
        threadHandle dd 0

section '.idata' import data readable
        library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll',\
        kernel, 'KERNEL32.DLL'

        import msvcrt,\
          system, 'system',\
          printf, 'printf',\
          exit, 'exit'

        import kernel,\
          CreateThread, 'CreateThread',\
          WaitForSingleObject, 'WaitForSingleObject',\
          Sleep, 'Sleep'
```

Comment: The threads are switching between the cores. You can set the affinity of a thread if you want and choose the cores on which they execute.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. But what is the motivation for switching cores? Wouldn't it cause a cache invalidation each time you switch to a different slot? I thought that you normally try to run critical code on a same core to keep caches hot... 
Or if I write some actual code that deals with mutable state hardware will choose a different strategy?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Windows seems to like to spread the load across the even cores (with HT disable it likes all cores). I would have used the "keep caches hot" as argument for keeping a thread on the same core as much as possible, I don't know why they don't do it that way.

Comment: One possible reason could be to spread heat more evenly across the cpu die.

Comment: Also, the task manager itself, and other 'base-load' stuff on most boxes - network activity, AV apps etc. that use up like 1-2% of the box even when you are not 'doing anything' will require threads.  Occasionally, (and I have no idea how often, but the 5 sec between TM refreshes is a long time in CPU terms), these kernel and user threads will likely use up all the cores briefly and preempt one of your threads. When the spike in base-load drops, your preeempted thread will likely be shovelled back onto the first core that becomes free.

Comment: Oh - just checked - Task Manager itself has six threads and, presumably, they have a very high priority. The TM itself may displace all your threads when it runs.

Comment: Thinking about it, if you were asked 'design a "task manager" to collect statistics, how would you do it?  One way that occurs to me to get reasonably accurate stats is to run as many very-high-priority threads as there are cores to quickly take a snapshot of the stats before going back to sleep again.  That would probably move around some of the other threads.

Comment: What is a good way to trace which core is actually executing a thread at a given time? Just to make sure that those loaded cores are really busy incrementing counter.

Comment: One other reason it might spread the load is to use less power. Running two CPUs full-blast can use more power than using 4 CPUs and sleeping them half the time. This is a common optimization, as laptops and smartphones become more prevalent, but you are correct that it will invalidate your caches.